# Facebook Webhook

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to make facebook application to manage business page personal messages and comments from one person. Messages with messanger api are retrieve good (only from my personal account, not another). But webhooks about new comments are not working. I need to add this feature but for now I cant undestand what I doing wrong. I need to make few simple tests in realtime. What i need to make it available? Do i need to confirm business account to proceed with realtime webhook data?

Im receiving messages and put them to log, but only test comment is available for me now. Thats test webhook i receive from api. I also think that I receive not comment data, otherwise feed (new post) data.

```
{
"entry": 
  [{
    "id": "0", 
    "time": 1703605238, 
    "changes": [{
      "field": "feed", 
      "value": {
        "item": "status", 
        "post_id": "44444444_444444444", 
        "verb": "add", 
        "published": 1, 
        "created_time": 1703605238,
        "message": "Example post content.", 
        "from": @
          "name": "Test Page", 
          "id": "1067280970047460"
      }
    }]
  }], 
"object": "page"
}
```

Comment: Please post as text, not as screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only receiving test data, there might be an issue with the webhook setup or permissions. So make sure you have these permissions:

- `pages_manage_metadata`
- `pages_read_engagement`
- `pages_manage_posts`

If not fixed, check the App Dashboard for any error messages or warnings.

Comment: It might be because my app isn't publicised. I cant found such options on webhook management page (developers.facebook.com/app-id/webhooks) on tab "page" but i already enabled all options here. All this options is active with standart access, and pages_read_engagement is used 5 times. I think it is permissions, not webhook settings but thank for reply.